# How can I compute the probability of $X_1$ being the largest among $X_i$s?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How can I compute the probability of $X_1$ being the largest among $X_i$s?

The random variable $X_i$ follows $\Gamma(\alpha_i,1)$ independently.

I think that $P(\max(X_i) = X_1) = \prod_{j\ne 1} P(X_1 > X_j)$ because of indendence.

Am I right?

Comment: This might be a silly idea, but isn't the probability just $\frac{1}{n}$, where $n$ is the number of of $X_i$'s ? Being the biggest among a group is a feature that exactly one of the elements has, and each one of the elements has equal probability of getting it ... I might be talking complete nonsense here but that's what I'm thinking.

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks for comment. I think If the $X_i$'s follow identical distribution, the probability can be $\frac{1}{n}$. But their distribution isn't identical ;(

Comment: The events are not independent since $X_1$ present in every event.

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha_i=\alpha$ for all $i$, then by symmetry  $P(\max(X_i) = X_1 ) = 1/n$, where $i=1, \ldots, n$.

Now, if $X_i \sim \Gamma(1,\lambda_i)$ you have an exponential distribution.  In that case, it is well known that 
\begin{equation}
P(X_1>X_2) = P(X_1= \max(X_1,X_2))=  \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_2+\lambda_1}
\end{equation}
but
\begin{equation}
P(X_1>X_2, X_1>X_3) = P(X_1= \max(X_1,X_2,X_3))= P(X_1>X_2 | X_1>X_3) P(X_1>X_3) 
\end{equation}
which is different from $P(X_1> X_2) P(X_1>X_3)$.

So, in general I think you need to search for the literature on order statistics to answer your question

Gupta, S. S. (1960). Order statistics from the gamma distribution. Technometrics, 2(2), 243-262.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/1266548?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents